# How to keep track of Azure IotHub device connection state?

Tags: node.js, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I managed to connect my device to Azure IoTHub via the `azure-iot-device` npm package with mqtt protocol, retrieve the device twin, and send events etc. However, I need to build some connection resiliency into the device and that's where things start getting a little hairy. Specifically, I want to know if the device is online and connected before I send data, otherwise I might choose to write to file instead, and send again when its reconnected.

However, tried querying connectionState as per documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/monitor-device-connection-state#device-twin-connectionstate) but `client.connectionState` or `twin.connectionState` or `client.connected` were undefined and did not work. I also tried connecting locally from my computer and then manually turning off the Wifi, and after ~3-5 mins which I guess is the keep-alive time for mqtt, it did a process exit without triggering any of the below on('error') or on('close') listeners.

1. Is the way I've setup the event listeners for error and connection close events correct? I can see `Connected to IoT Hub - xxx` in terminal logs when I connect though.
2. Is there some inbuilt method or getter I can use to check for the connection state?
3. If all else fails, I would probably need to use event listeners to trigger a flag that I can check. How can I listen for at least an error or a connection close event?

Thanks in advance!

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

const { Mqtt } = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt');
const { Client } = require('azure-iot-device');

// Azure filepath
const azPrivateKeyFilePath = join(__dirname, './rsa_private_key.key');
const azCertificateFilePath = join(__dirname, './rsa_cert.crt');

//===================================
const device_id = 'xxx';
var deviceConnectionString = `xxx`;

const connOptions = {
    cert : fs.readFileSync(azCertificateFilePath, 'utf-8').toString(),
    key : fs.readFileSync(azPrivateKeyFilePath, 'utf-8').toString()  
};

function establishIoTHubConnection() {
    iotHubClient = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Mqtt);
    iotHubClient.setOptions(connOptions);
    
    iotHubClient.open().catch((err) => {        
        iotHubLastError = err.message;
        console.log('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
    });
    
    // MQTT event triggers
    iotHubClient.on('connect', function(){
        console.log(`Connected to IoT Hub - ${device_id}`);
        // Register device method handlers
    });

    iotHubClient.on('error', function(event) {
        console.log('WHAT IS THIS EVENT', event);
    })
    
    iotHubClient.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed for IoT Hub.');
    });
    

    // Get the device twin (gateway config)
    iotHubClient.getTwin(async (err, twin) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Could not get device config (device twin)');
        } else {
            twin.on('properties.desired', function (desiredState) {
                const { config } = desiredState;
                if (config) {
                    const configString = JSON.stringify(config);
                    console.log('UPDATING DEVICE CONFIG', configString);
                }
            });

            console.log('TWIN STATE', twin.connectionState);
        }
    });
}

establishIoTHubConnection();
```

Comment: do you want to know the connection state of the IoT Hub device with mqtt

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to get the state in a program but I am sure these steps might get you an idea.

There is a built-in way to get the state from your connections using **EventGrid**.

First, enable **EventGrid** on your Subscription as **Resource provider** in the **Settings**.

Then, configure subscription for **IoT Hub** events.

1. Go to your IoT Hub resource and click on Events in the left-pane.
2. Create an Event Subscription with a name and Event Grid Schema as schema.
3. Define a name for your topic.
4. Select Device Connected and Device Disconnected.

From this point the steps you should follow may change, but take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/OscarSantosMu/GlobalAzure2022#configure-subscription-for-iot-hub-events) where I used low code approach with a webhook. My workflow basically sends me an email when EventGrid detects a change in the device state.

I guess, instead of a webhook, you need to read this event at your node.js code with the SDKs. Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/eventgrid-readme?view=azure-node-latest#deserializing-an-event).

Probably, something like this:

```
const { EventGridDeserializer, isSystemEvent } = require("@azure/eventgrid");

const consumer = new EventGridDeserializer();

const event = (await consumer.deserializeCloudEvents(message.body))[0];

if (isSystemEvent("Microsoft.Devices.DeviceConnected", event)) {
    console.log(
        `${event.time}: Device connected. Send data`
    );
} else if (isSystemEvent("Microsoft.Devices.DeviceDisconnected", event)) {
    console.log(
        `${event.time}: Device disconnected. Write to a file`
    );
}
```

Comment: Was referring to how I could get the connection state from within the device. For e.g. mqtt has a `Client.connected` method here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#connected